# Boost interprocess: cout a string variable when iterating through a map that references an object from a struct

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, struct

I'm using boost::interprocess to share objects between processes.
I have two files, a "server.cpp" that generates a struct object and passes the object into a map with an int index; and a "client.cpp" file that retrieves the memory data and iterates through the data, outputting to console.

The struct looks like this:

```
    struct mydata o {
    string MY_STRING;
    int MY_INT; 
};
```

And the object:

```
mydata o;
o.MY_STRING = "hello";
o.MY_INT = 45;
```

Both server and client compile correctly.
But for some reason the client executable throws a segmentation fault if I try to access a string rather than a float or an integer in the client.
For example the below second.MY_INT will cout to console, but second.MY_STRING throws this error when running.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "objects.cpp" //definitions for objects
using std::string;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

    int main ()
{

    try
    {
            managed_shared_memory segment(open_or_create, "SharedMemoryName",65536);

            //Again the map<Key, MappedType>'s value_type is std::pair<const Key, MappedType>, so the allocator must allocate that pair.
            typedef int    KeyType;
            typedef order  MappedType;
            typedef std::pair<const int, order> ValueType;

            //Assign allocator 
            typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

            //The map
            typedef map<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MySHMMap;

            //Initialize the shared memory STL-compatible allocator
            ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

            //access the map in SHM through the offset ptr                                                         
            MySHMMap :: iterator iter;
            offset_ptr<MySHMMap> m_pmap = segment.find<MySHMMap>("MySHMMapName").first;

            iter=m_pmap->begin();
            for(; iter!=m_pmap->end();iter++)
            {
                   //std::cout<<"\n "<<iter->first<<" "<<iter->second;
                   std::cout<<iter->first<<" "<<iter->second.MYINT<<" "<<iter->second.MYSTRING<<"\n";
            }
    }catch(std::exception &e)            
    {
            std::cout<<" error  " << e.what() <<std::endl;
           shared_memory_object::remove("SharedMemoryName");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the error when running:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm pretty sure the server is passing the entire object to memory, and the client can retrieve it (as i can access some of the objects attributes), and that its just a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some great info from previous posters led me to a simple answer of my own. Use a char array in the struct, then read it into a string as follows:

```
std::cout<<iter->first<<" "<<iter->second.ORDERTYPE<<" "<<string(iter->second.MYID)<<"\n";
```

here is the struct I speak of:

```
struct order {
    char MYID[100];
    int ORDERTYPE;
    char DATE_UPDATED[64];
};
order o
```

here is how i passed the struct into memory:

```
m_pmap->insert(std::pair<const int, order>(i, (order)o));
```

now i am able to write a map of structs containing various types including strings, to memory, and retrieve them from memory.

Answer (score 3):

Like Justin mentioned, `std::string` is itself a container that dynamically allocates.

Just using Interprocess's `string` is not enough. In fact, that's just `boost::container::basic_string<>` really.

*The important thing is using the allocator.*

However, using a map with an allocator, and passing the allocator whenever you need to construct the contained containers (ad nauseam) is annoying.

### Enter Scoped Allocators

These make it so that you don't have to *know* the allocator, any container that knows how to use scoped allocators will pass the allocator onto the nested container.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/248ea5f1163ffbb5)</kbd>** ¹

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace Shared {
    using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using Alloc 
        = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Manager> >;

    using String = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char> >;

    template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K> > using Map 
        = bip::map<K, V, Cmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V> > >;

    struct Order {
        using allocator_type = Alloc<char>;

        template <typename S, typename Alloc>
        Order(int i, S const& s, Alloc alloc = {}) : i(i), s(s, alloc) {}

        int    i;
        String s;
    };
}

int main() {
    try {
        using namespace Shared;
        Segment segment(bip::open_or_create, "095540a3-ceaa-4431-828d-df21d5e384ae", 65536);

        auto& pmap = *segment.find_or_construct<Map<int, Order>>("MySHMMapName")(segment.get_segment_manager());

        if (pmap.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Inserting data\n";
            auto insert = [&pmap](int i, auto&& s) {
                using namespace std;
                pmap.emplace(piecewise_construct, tie(i), tie(i, s));
            };

            insert(1, "one");
            insert(2, "two");
            insert(3, "three");
        } else {
            std::cout << "Existing data:\n";
            for (auto& [k,v] : pmap) {
                std::cout << k << " " << v.i << " " << v.s << "\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << " error  " << e.what() << std::endl;
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove("095540a3-ceaa-4431-828d-df21d5e384ae");
    }
}
```

### Making It More Elegant

I notice that the map is `Map<int, Order>`: the key seems to duplicate the integer value inside `Order`.

#### Option 1: `Map<int, String>`

You could either make it `Map<int, String>` and get a much more streamlined experience (because there's no need for `std::piecewise_construct`):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/067ece5dea37fd31)</kbd>**

```
auto& pmap = *segment.find_or_construct<Map<int, String>>("MySHMMapName")(segment.get_segment_manager());

if (pmap.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Inserting data\n";

    pmap.emplace(1, "one");
    pmap.emplace(2, "two");
    pmap.emplace(3, "three");
}
```

#### Option 2: Multi Index

Alternatively, you should consider using Multi-Index which is able to index `Order` directly by a member of the type:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/642230f51c329f8d)</kbd>**

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
using Table = bmi::multi_index_container<Order,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique< bmi::member<Order, int, &Order::i> >
    >,
    Alloc<Order>
>;
```

Sadly, Multi Index doesn't quite play as well with nested types using allocators, so you'll have to pass it along again:

```
if (pmap.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Inserting data\n";

    pmap.emplace(1, "one", pmap.get_allocator());
    pmap.emplace(2, "two", pmap.get_allocator());
    pmap.emplace(3, "three", pmap.get_allocator());
} else {
    std::cout << "Existing data:\n";
    for (Order const& o : pmap) {
        std::cout << o.i << " " << o.s << "\n";
    }

    // demonstrate lookup:
    std::cout << "Finding element 2:" << pmap.find(2)->s << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Existing data:
1 one
2 two
3 three
Finding element 2:two
```

---

¹ using mapped files on Coliru instead. The refactored code makes this a 1-line change.

Answer (score 2):

> But for some reason the client executable throws a segmentation fault if I try to access a string rather than a float or an integer in the client.

It looks like you are using `std::string` in your structure within the shared memory map. You cannot do this, since `std::string` allocates it's own memory which goes out of scope with `boost::interprocess`.  You should try using the `boost::interprocess::basic_string` type in place of `std::string`.  There is an example of how to use this in an interprocess map [in the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers)

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
```